# find the solution set of the following inequality

Tags: inequality

with so many radical I get lost

**$\sqrt[4]{\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-3x-4}}{\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{x^{2}-4}}}\geqslant x-5$**

**Edit
I get online with wolfram

 -5 < x <= -2 || x == -1 || 4 <= x < 5**

Comment: Where did you find this monster?

Comment: It is for my son who is just beginning

Comment: But why  $-1$ , if we substitute  $ \sqrt{(-1)^2 -4} = \sqrt{ -3}$ !!

Answer (score 2):

First let us check where the above formula is defined:

$ x^2-3x-4 \geq 0  \; \; \Leftrightarrow  \; \; x\in ] -\infty , -1] \cup [4,+\infty[$.

$x^2-4 \geq  0  \; \; \Leftrightarrow  \; \; x\in ] -\infty , -2] \cup [2,+\infty[ $.

$ \sqrt{21 } - \sqrt{ x^2-4} > 0  \; \; \Leftrightarrow  \; \;  x\in   ]-5,-2[ \cup ]2,5[.$

Thus  You set of solution must  be subset of  $]-5, -2] \cup [4,5[ $. Note that whenever $x  \in   ]-5, -2] \cup [4,5[ $ the inequality holds true as  $x-5 < 0 $ and the other side  of the inequality is surely positive.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{\sqrt{x^{2}-3x-4}}{\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{x^{2}-4}}}\ge0$

So, one immediate solution is $x-5<0\iff x<5$

Otherwise i.e., if  $x\ge5$

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-3x-4}}{\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{x^2-4}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{(x-4)(x+1)(\sqrt{21}+\sqrt{x^2-4})}}{25-x^2}$$ which will be $<0$ if $x>5$

and what if $x=5$?

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is a very messy problem.
We start off with:
**$\sqrt[4]{\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-3x-4}}{\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{x^{2}-4}}}\geqslant x-5$**

Now we can raise each side to the power $4$.

${\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-3x-4}}{\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{x^{2}-4}}}\geqslant (x-5)^4$

We can then multiply the denominator to the right side:

$\sqrt{x^{2}-3x-4}\geqslant(x-5)^4 * (\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{x^{2}-4})$

From here, again we can square both sides, receiving:

${x^{2}-3x-4}\geqslant(x-5)^8 * (\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{x^{2}-4})²$

Afterwards, you can expand these.

Comment: it is very complicated from there do not know how to handle that expression

Comment: No one likes to solve 8th degree polynomials...